# Formatting array of NSString and Display in NSLog

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsstring, nsarray

I have sorted Core Data attributes into an array based on the Entity *Material* and one it's attributes *category* and wish to display the stored answers in NSLog.

This is the code that I have used to get my desired answers:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Materials"];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Materials" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

// Required! Unless you set the resultType to NSDictionaryResultType, distinct can't work. 
// All objects in the backing store are implicitly distinct, but two dictionaries can be duplicates.
// Since you only want distinct Categories, only ask for the 'Category' property.
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"Category"]];
fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
NSArray * arrayWithCatNames = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

NSLog (@"Categories: %@",arrayWithCatNames);
```

**Without using the `NSString` formatting code I get this**

```
2014-12-19 11:28:48.648 App2.0[31085:2652989] Category Names: (
    {
    category = "Bakelite";
 },
    {
    category = "BOXES, BRACKETS AND BLOCKS";
 },
    {
    category = MISCELLANEOUS;
 },
 )
```

I need it to display individually without commas and without brackets. Because it sorting and storing differently than most arrays it is not displaying correctly. I used the 'NSString * name = [NSString stringWithFormat: ...];' amongst some other variations to try and sort better, which i did improve however it did not solve the problem.

Some also have the quotations and others don't which I have not saved that way. Does anyone know why that occurs? Thanks.**This was answered in comments** - using commas or other symbols (even spaces sometimes) causes the quotation marks.

This is my question from yesterday about getting a specific attribute from core data: 
[Displaying Core Data: If attribute has same name display once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538930/displaying-core-data-if-attribute-has-same-name-display-once)

My question is how do I display in `NSLog` each category like "Category: %@, arrayWithCatNames"?

**UPDATE**

I discovered the answer to my question and posted below.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67335/discussion-on-question-by-sasmith-formatting-array-of-nsstring-and-display-in-ns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer with a little help from [HotLicks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/581994/hot-licks)  pointing me in the right direction.

**I changed the name of the array to help with confusion:

```
// No longer "dictionaries"
NSArray * arrayOfStrings = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
id value = [arrayOfStrings valueForKey:@"category"];
for (NSString * str in value) {

     NSLog (@"Category Names: %@",str);

}
```

I added it at the end of my code and removed the `NSString * name` code. Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Materials"];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Materials" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

// Required! Unless you set the resultType to NSDictionaryResultType, distinct can't work. 
// All objects in the backing store are implicitly distinct, but two dictionaries can be duplicates.
// Since you only want distinct Categories, only ask for the 'Category' property.
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"Category"]];
fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
NSArray *arrayOfResults = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
//Convert to String to print better, still not working
NSArray * categories = [arrayOfResults  valueForKey:@"category"];
```

Here you get array of categories and you can use it as datasource in UITableview Methods and also you can get sorted categories from core data during fetch. Let me know if you want me to do that for you.